# Target accordion pane content template after databind so that I can load data on demand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an accordion that has another accordion inside one of its panes. This inner accordion is created using a datasource so each of its panes are loaded from a list of objects. In this particular case, this datasource is also loaded on demand. Now, where I'm stuck is that I want to be able to load the pane headers only and then load the contents when the pane is clicked; similar to what I have in the outer pane. The reason I'm confused here, is because the lazy load happens when the pane is clicked, but since this happens AFTER the databind, I don't know how to reference the content of the pane that invokes the ItemCommand. Not sure if that makes sense. Here is the inner accordion:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion runat="server" ID="accReviewers" OnItemDataBound="accOuterAccordion_ItemDataBound" ContentCssClass="ReviewerContent" RequireOpenedPane="False" SelectedIndex="-1" OnItemCommand="accReviewers_ItemCommand">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("Header") %>' CssClass="InReviewHeader" runat="server" 
                    CommandName="LoadReviewers" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MocRequestId") %>'/>    
                </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvReviewers" ItemPlaceholderID="phReviewer" OnItemDataBound="lvReviewers_ItemDataBound">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkGotoRequest" Text="View this request"/>
                            </div>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phReviewer"/>
                            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnResubmit" Text="Resubmit" CssClass="ResubmitInitial"/>    
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="ReviewerItem">
                                <%#Eval("Assignee.Name") %><br />
                                <img src="" alt="Reviewer" runat="server" ID="imgReviewer" width="75" style="border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 6px;"/><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%#Eval("ReviewStatus") %>' />
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkRejectComment" CssClass="InitialRejectComment">(details)</asp:HyperLink>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
    </Content>  
</ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

As you can see, the accordion accReviewers is generated via a DataSource. The listview contained in the LayoutTemplate will not have its datasource bound until the LinkButton has been clicked, which will fire the item command. Also worth noting that this entire accordion is wrapped in an UpdatePanel.

This is the code behind I was starting to work with, but it doesn't appear to get the correct instance of the listview and while the list is not empty, it will not display anything:

```
    protected void accReviewers_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var mocId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        var list = (sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion).FindControl("lvReviewers") as ListView; //APPARENTLY WRONG
        var reviewers = MocApi.GetReviews(mocId); 
        list.DataSource = reviewers;
        list.DataBind();
    }
```

So to recap, when the LinkButton within the HeaderTemplate is clicked, I need to somehow gain reference to the correct instance of the ListView so that I can bind its datasource. As always, any help or insight is appreciated. This is similar to a previous question of mine but is specific to gaining this reference after databind which seems a bit more complicated. TIA

UPDATE:
I found that I can bind the item datasource if I can somehow capture its index. I'm exploring trying to set that as a command argument during the databinding of the inner accordion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with some minor shenannigans:

Here is the markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="ReviewerItem">
        <%#Eval("Assignee.Name") %><br />
        <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
            <img src="" alt="Reviewer" runat="server" ID="imgReviewer" width="75" style="border: 1px solid lightgray; border-radius: 6px; overflow: hidden;"/><br />    
            <div runat="server" ID="divYes" Visible="False">
                <img src="../Images/Yes.png" alt="Approved" class="ApprovalIcon"  />
            </div>
            <div runat="server" ID="divNo" Visible="False">
                <img src="../Images/No.png" alt="Rejected" class="ApprovalIcon" id="imgNo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%#Eval("ReviewStatus") %>' />
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkRejectComment" CssClass="InitialRejectComment">(details)</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlDemoApproval" Visible="False" CssClass="DemoButtons">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnApprove" Text="Approve" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Assignee.Guid") + "|" + Eval("Ticketid") %>' CommandName="ApproveReview"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeny" Text="Deny" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Assignee.Guid") + "|" + Eval("Ticketid") %>' CommandName="DenyReview"/>
        </asp:Panel>
        <ajaxToolkit:BalloonPopupExtender runat="server" ID="balloon" BalloonPopupControlID="pnlPopup"
        TargetControlID="lnkRejectComment" Position="TopRight" BalloonStyle="Cloud" BalloonSize="Medium" DisplayOnMouseOver="True"/>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopup">Rejection Reason</asp:Panel>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

On databind, I catch the item so that I can grab the index and set it to the CommandName for later use:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ItemType != AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionItemType.Content) return;
    var index = e.ItemIndex;
    var button = e.AccordionItem.Parent.FindControl("lnkbHeader") as LinkButton;
    if (button != null) button.CommandName = index.ToString();
}
```

Now that control contains the index, i can use that to target the correct pane and bind its datasource:

```
protected void accReviewers_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //This seems stupid to put here, but for some reason the item command bypasses the listview catch and passes it to the accordion

    if (e.CommandName == "ApproveReview")
    {
        var assigneeGuid = new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|')[0]);
        var ticketId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|')[1]);
        var ticket = new MocApproval(ticketId);
        DoDemoApproval(ticketId, assigneeGuid, true);
        var approvalIndex = (sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion).SelectedIndex;
        var lv =
            (sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion).Panes[approvalIndex].FindControl("lvReviewers") as ListView;
        lv.DataSource = MocApi.GetReviews(ticket.MocRequest);
        lv.DataBind();
        return;
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "DenyReview")
    {
        var assigneeGuid = new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|')[0]);
        var ticketId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('|')[1]);
        var ticket = new MocApproval(ticketId);
        DoDemoApproval(ticketId, assigneeGuid, false);
        var approvalIndex = (sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion).SelectedIndex;
        var lv =
            (sender as AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion).Panes[approvalIndex].FindControl("lvReviewers") as ListView;
        lv.DataSource = MocApi.GetReviews(ticket.MocRequest);
        lv.DataBind();
        return;
    }

    ...
```